# How to set my IP address to default url for my page in Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I want to set my AWS instance's ip address(e.g. 52.172.33.23) to my default page, which means when I put 52.172.33.23 on web browser, my application works without `server_name`. So, I set `/opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf` like,

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    passenger_enabled on;
    root /home/ec2-user/my_app/public;
}
```

But server running works with `sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`, but nothing shows on my ip address.

Additionally, I opened `port 3000`, and changed `listen 80 default_server;` to `listen 3000 default_server;` it worked on `52.172.33.23:3000` not on `52.172.33.23`. Also, curiously, I don't have `log/production.log` file.

Are there any suggestions about this situation, or documents that I can read? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out proxy server in nginx documentation.

You can configure your nginx file like this as a start:

```
upstream backend {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  passenger_enabled on; # not sure about passenger, can try commenting out if it does not work
  # root /home/ec2-user/my_app/public;

  location / {
       proxy_pass http://backend;
       proxy_redirect     off;
       proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
       proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}
```

This is the configuration on my project. Hope this works for your case.

By the way, I think [here](https://serverfault.com/) is a more appropriate place to ask nginx related question.

Comment: Thank you for your comments and I will check it right away, and ask question to that site next time.